# Calling pointer to member function with passing this as parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, this, pointer-to-member, member-functions

While calling pointer to member function, we need to explicitly specify `this`:

```
(this->*ptr)();
```

If I understand correctly, we need to do that, since automatic parameter (`this`) passing doesn't work in this cases (maybe because we call member function using pointer to it). So I wonder, why can't we just call it and explicitly pass `this` as parameter?

```
ptr(this); / compile error
```

Comment: You can't simply do `Foo::bar(&instance_of_Foo);`.

Comment: Member function is just like any other function, but first parameter of it is this, right? So if I have pointer to it, why can't I just call it? Why do we have that restriction?

Comment: No, the first parameter is not `this`. The first parameter is what is declared in function declaration.

Comment: Come on, then how this is being passed to functions?

Comment: Classes became meaningful, because to work with the same data, we need to pass the same object to all functions that work with it. So, we create class, and that single parameter is being passed automatically. No magic I think, class is like a struct, and group of functions, that work with it, just we don't create struct, and pass it to each function, instead compiler does exactly the same thing for us. am I wrong?

Comment: Not specified in standard. E.g. On x86 architecture and depending on calling convention used, it can be passed via `ecx` register

Comment: *Member function is just like any other function, but first parameter of it is this, right?* No, it's different from any other function. The type is different, the syntax is different, the calling convention is potentially different.

Comment: *why can't we* Because the language rules say so. Why don't they say something different? There could be many reasons, for example, simplicity and uniformity of the syntax. There is no technical reason why `ptr(this)` couldn't work. It just doesn't.